# How to generate a date range in kdb excluding weekend days?

Tags: kdb

This code produces a sequence of dates:

```
firstdate: 2008.06.01
lastdate: 2008.08.31
daterange: firstdate + til (lastdate - firstdate) + 1
```

Is it possible to generate the same range excluding weekend dates (Sat/Sun)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
q)daterange where not (daterange mod 7) in 0 1 
2008.06.02 2008.06.03 2008.06.04 2008.06.05 2008.06.06 2008.06.09 2008.06.10 ..
q)
```

Comment: I tried to add this to a q script and get an error: "date_range: arg_begin_date + til (arg_end_date - arg_begin_date) + 1". The same line typed at the q console works...

Comment: Sorted out: arg_begin_date type in my script was 10h, rather than -14h as on the console.

Answer (score 4):

easier would be to do 
`daterange where 1<daterange mod 7`